# Entering a height in the parent element of a Nivo Bar Chart causes the whole page to go blank

Tags: javascript, nivo-react

I understand that for a Nivo Bar Chart to display, its parent element must have a defined height. However, when I define the height in the parent element, the entire page (including other React components) goes blank. Any thoughts on how to fix this and display my bar chart?

The offending snippet is as follows:

```
const MyResponsiveBar = ({ data /* see data tab */ }) => (
  <div style={{height: '500px'}}>
    <ResponsiveBar
        margin={{ top: 50, right: 130, bottom: 50, left: 60 }}
```